# disable redirect after submit form

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post)) {
    ...
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

and when i submit this form, i get redirect to /ControllerName/ActionName.
I can stop this if add *onsubmit* like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new {onsubmit="return Submit();"}))
```

and script like this

```
Submit = function() {
    ...
    return false;
}
```

Is there the true-way to prevent redirect without custom script?

UPD: the server-side code

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MySubmit(ParamsClass params)
    return new JsonResult {
        Data = BusinessLogicOperations();
    };
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to submit the form, don't use form.

Comment: i want to stay on current page after submit. for example: do you want to redirect after enter you email in form?

Comment: Show us the `Controller` code.

Comment: can't you use ajax to post instead of the whole page/form?

Comment: Use form without binding to controller and ajax for posting your data into API controller.

Comment: what if you're using SendGrid, which is not supported by AJAX apparently?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your post action:

[HttpPost]

```
public ActionResult MySubmit(ParamsClass params)
    // do your busines logic here

    return RedirectToAction("YourAction", "YourController", params);
}
```

Comment: yes, you right, but it initiate page reload.
i find the way to ajax submit form without reload and using scripts

Comment: @user3272018 without page reload it can be don by using ajax. But how you want to do it without using scripts?